# Assets: reference to another directory

Tags: android, reference, customization, assets

How can I change the reference to assets directory from the default one to a custom one (that I created and stored into the internal storage) programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The assets are read-only files that are included in the APK. If you want to read files from the internal storage, then you need to use the file-access API, for example: `openFileInput()`

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `AssetManager` works only with assets (`assets/` in your project).

Instead, you will need to wrap your access to assets in code that will conditionally use internal storage:

```
if (iCanHazInternalStorage()) {
  loadFromInternalStorage();
}
else {
  loadFromAssets();
}
```